# Coding Error Within Terminal?

Tags: games, steam

I own Terraria on Steam and its one of my favourite games. I finally got Steam working on my laptop and now it doesn't work. I don't know anything about code, so here's all the technical stuff.
Upon Loading Terraria with a Terminal window open:

```
/home/matt/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Terraria/Terraria: line 38: 29065 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./${BASENAME}.bin.${ext} $@
Game removed: AppID 105600 "Terraria", ProcID 29065 
No cached sticky mapping in ActivateActionSet.
```

After looking through the files I found the area mentioned above, and here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# MonoKickstart Shell Script
# Written by Ethan "flibitijibibo" Lee

# Move to script's directory
cd "`dirname "$0"`"

# Get the system architecture
UNAME=`uname`
ARCH=`uname -m`
BASENAME=`basename "$0"`

# MonoKickstart picks the right libfolder, so just execute the right binary.
if [ "$UNAME" == "Darwin" ]; then
    ext=osx
else
    ext=x86
    for arg in "$@"
    do
        case "$arg" in
        -x86)   ext=x86
            ;;
        -x64)   ext=x86_64
            ;;
        -autoarch)
            if [ "$ARCH" == "x86_64" ]; then
                ext=x86_64
            else
                ext=x86
            fi
            ;;
        esac
    done
fi


export MONO_IOMAP=all
./${BASENAME}.bin.${ext} $@
```